# Proof regarding homogeneous functions of degree $n$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $n$, show that $f_{x}(tx,ty) = t^{n-1}f_{x}(x,y)$.

My attempt at a solution:

Let $u = tx$ and $v = ty$.$$\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$ But $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = t$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0.$ Hence,
        $$t\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u} = t^{n}f_{x}(x,y)$$ or $$\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u} = t^{n-1}f_{x}(x,y).$$ How do I get from the term on the left hand side to $\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial x}$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977677/property-of-homogeneous-functions-in-two-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}$ means partial derivative with respect to the first variable, which is also denoted by $f_x(u,v)$. Here the subscript $x$ denotes that the partial derivative is with respect to the first variable $u=tx$ and not $x$ itself. So in our case $\frac {\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}=f_x(u,v)=f_x(tx,ty)=t^{n-1}f_x(x,y)$ and you are already done.